# Mandar embed random Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

¿Como puedo mandar un `embed random`? En *Discord.py*

Se como hacerlo con texto normal pero ¿en un `embed` como?

Comment: ¿Tienes una lista de embeds y quieres mandar uno aleatoriamente o generar un embed con datos aleatorios?

Comment: Quierobsaber como hacer la lista y mandarlos

Comment: ¿Pero los tienes ya creados (instanciados) o necesita crearlos desde aalguna fuente de datos? Si puedes agregar un [mcve] sería de ayuda paa da contexto a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Primero tenes que crear la variable de cada uno de los embed, cuando lo hagas asegurate de tener importado el modulo random:

```
import random
```

entonces podes hacer esto:

```
random.choice(embed1, embed2, embed3)
```

y asi podes definir la aleatoriedad

supongo que ya sabes como hacer que eso se pueda enviar o definir. saludos